# Remap ⌘S to save a file in VIM

Tags: vim, macvim, iterm

I have recently switched from using MacVim to just using Vim on the command line.  One feature I miss is being able to save a file with ⌘S rather than having to go back into normal mode and then :wq

I am using Vim inside iTerm2.  Is there any way to get ⌘S to save a file both in insert and normal mode?

Comment: Just curious, why'd you switch from MacVim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to map to ⌘ in the console version of Vim.  If you want to be able to use ⌘ in a mapping you'll need to switch back to MacVim.

Answer (score 5):

You can use iTerm2 to map `Cmd-S` to some other combination that the shell and Vim will recognize (e.g. `Ctrl+S`) , then you can simply map that command via a .vimrc file as Andrew pointed out.

In summary:

- edit iTerm2 Keys with a new entry that maps Cmd-S to `Ctrl+S`.
- Add commands for mapping `Ctrl+S` to vimrc file (like Andrew describes) or like [this site](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-S_to_save_current_or_new_files).

Comment: Thank a bunch for the hint. I want to make this a bit more concrete. I mapped cmd-s to send hex code 0x1b 0x4f 0x51 which corresponds to F2. Then, in vimrc I add imap <F2> <C-O>:update<CR> .

Comment: +1 for iTerm2. It is a great terminal emulator with many extra nice features that make it great for using vim in the console.

Comment: @PitiOngmongkolkul how did you get that hex code for F2??? I could find out that F2 has the 0x78 keycode, but no idea how to transform that into a scape hex code

Comment: I recalled that I have it printed out the key I press in vi somehow. Can't exactly remember how though...

Answer (score 4):

Here is an even simpler way to do it: using iTerm2's "Send Text". Basically you can map `Cmd-S` to send a text to the current vim session `:w\n`.

[image: Send Text: <code>:w\n</code>]

Comment: I can confirm this worked -- but what does `:w\n` actually mean in the context of vimscript?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure that command-line Vim can register the ⌘ key, and I'm not on my Mac to confirm, but you can map ⌘S in .vimrc like this.

```
inoremap <D-s> <ESC>:w<CR>i  "insertmode
nnoremap <D-s> :w<CR>        "normalmode
```

Again, this will only work if command-line vim can recognize the ⌘key.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when using command line Vim in iTerm2.  It looks like the ⌘S is not getting through to Vim, it's just calling the iTerm command instead (Save text as).

Comment: If iTerm is catching it, then you're out of luck (as far as I know). You could always try <C-s> to map ctrl-s, or try pressing alt-s and mapping that.